# Do i have to use django-registration?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-login

I have a directory structure like this.

```
myProject
 --myApp
  --templates
   --registration
    --login.html
```

in myApp.urls.py i have a line like this

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')
```

In settings

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ()
```

when i try

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/"
```

i got

```
"TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
registration/login.html"
```

error. In google searchs i find advises like add django-registration to your app.

Do i have to?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use django-registration.

As long as you write the template `registraion/login.html`, you should be good to go.

Your template should be like:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
{{form.as_table}}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Make sure your template can be found by django. You will have to set proper TEMPLATE_DIRS for it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple because that is now how you work with django-logins and users. You need to append this to your `settings.py` file.

`LOGIN_URL = '<PATH_YOU_WANT>'`

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '<Redirect_after_log_in>'`